# JS Error: <parameter>.contains is not a function, not sure why

Tags: javascript, string, contains

I've been writing some JavaScript code, and introduced this small function:

```
function decodeLink(thelink) {
    console.log(typeof(thelink)); // Reports 'string'

    if (thelink.contains("something")) {
        // Cool condition
    }
}
```

However, if I was to call `decodeLink("hello");`, I get this error:

`TypeError: thelink.contains is not a function`

Note that I'm using node.js and discord.js, however commenting the imports out yields no results.

I've been using to the strongly typed C# style of programming, this weak typing is quite new to me. I'm sure I've missed something important (such as some explicit way to tell the program it's dealing with a string), but no search lead me closer as to what...

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `.includes()`?

Comment: You're looking for `includes` i guess read here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you need is called [includes](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp) not contains

```js
function decodeLink(thelink) {
    console.log(typeof(thelink)); // Reports 'string'

    if (thelink.includes("something")) {
        // Cool condition
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course it'd be a different keyword, I just assumed it'd be the same as C#... I'll be sure to mark this as answer in 10 minutes. Again thank you so much :)